# particle fields undefined local variable or method `f'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 particles that have forms inside them. I am calling these particles on my edit view page. I am getting an error saying "undefined local variable or method `f'" I am trying to define f, but I believe I am confused as to what syntax and convention to use. I believe I am close but I am a little mixed up.

views/ideas/edit.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "ideas_nav" %>

<h1><%= @idea.working_name %></h1>

<div id="idea_show_container">
 <%= form_for @idea  do |f| %>
 <div id="basic_details" class="idea-show-columns">
   <%= render :partial => 'idea_basic_edit', @ideas => {:f => f} %>
   <%= render :partial => 'comments', @ideas => {:f => f}  %>
   <%= render :partial => 'mockups', @ideas => {:f => f} %>
</div>

<% if current_user.has_copywriter_access? %>
   <div id="copy_details" class="idea-show-columns">
    <%= render :partial => 'copy_edit', @ideas => {:f => f}  %>
   </div>
<% end %>


<% if current_user.has_artist_access? %>
    <div id="art_details" class="idea-show-columns ">
        <%= render :partial => 'art_edit', @ideas => {:f => f} %>
    </div>
<% end %>

</div>

  <%= f.submit %>
  <%end%>
```

one of the particles _idea_basic_edit.erb:

```
  <fieldset data-model="idea-basic" class="idea-edit">
  <h2>Basic Idea Specs</h2>

 <div data-attribute="product_sku" class="edit-field">
  <%= label :sku, "Product SKU" %>
  <%= f.text_field :sku %>
</div>

 <div data-attribute="working_name" class="edit-field">
   <%= label :working_name, "Working Name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :working_name %>
 </div>
<div data-attribute="priority" class="edit-field">
   <%= f.label :priority, 'Priority Level' %>
   <%= f.select :priority, Idea::PRIORITIES.collect{ |level, label| [label, level]} %>
</div>

<% if current_user.has_overlord_access? %>
    <div data-attribute="overlord_id" class="edit-field">
      <%= f.label :overlord_id, 'Sign Off' %>
      <%= f.select :overlord_id, User.overlords.collect{|o| [o.full_name, o.id]}, 
:include_blank => true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<br data-clear="all" />
<div data-attribute="working_description" class="edit-field">
  <%= label :working_description, "Working Description" %>
  <%= f.text_area :working_description %>

</div>
  </fieldset>
```

idea controller configs:

```
def edit
  @idea = Idea.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
end

 def update
  @idea = Idea.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
  if request.xhr?
  if params[:comment]
    @idea.comments.create(:title => params[:comment][:title], :comment => params[:comment]
[:comment], :user_id => current_user.id)
  end
  if @idea.update_attributes(update_status_params)
    @success = true
  else
    @success = false
  end
else
  if @idea.update_attributes(edit_idea_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Idea updated!'
    redirect_to idea_url(params[:id])
  else
    render :edit
    end
  end
end

def edit_idea_params
(params[:idea][:color_ids] ||= []) unless !current_user.has_artist_access?
(params[:idea][:imprintable_ids] ||= []) unless !current_user.has_copywriter_access?
(params[:idea][:stores_ids] ||= []) unless !current_user.has_copywriter_access?
(params[:idea][:taxonomies_ids] ||= []) unless !current_user.has_copywriter_access?

 params.require(:idea).permit(:sku, :working_name, :working_description, :priority,     
 :product_name, :product_line_tokens,
                             :description, :meta_description, :meta_keywords, :artist_id, 
 :copywriter_id, :overlord_id,
                              {:store_ids => []}, {:taxonomy_ids => []}, :base_price, 
 :shipping_category, :default_artwork_id,
                              :tax_category, {:imprintable_ids => []}, :marketplace, 
 :product_type, 
                              :base, :colors_offered, :special_instructions, :copy_status, 
 :art_status, {:color_ids => []}, 
                              :artworks_attributes => [:height, :width, :from_top, 
 :from_center, :idea_id, :dimensions, :file, :_destroy, :id])
 end
```

log:

```
Started PATCH "/ideas/bpul_dishes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-07 13:07:29 -0500
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM 
`schema_migrations`
Processing by IdeasController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"FTWlXzQpJYQBE4fCV2z9jZddpx3Epf5ZBecOEfax4eA=", "idea"=>{"sku"=>"     
 bpul_dishe", "working_name"=>"DO ME (DIRTY DISHES)", "priority"=>"5", "overlord_id"=>"", 
"working_description"=>"\"Hey, Ann Arbor T-shirt Company - you know what we want? A sexy 
dishwashing shirt\", said the people. And lo, the Ann Arbor T-shirt Company did deliver.", 
"copy_status"=>"Awaiting Approval", "copywriter_id"=>"", "product_name"=>"DO ME (DIRTY 
DISHES)", "description"=>"\"Hey, Ann Arbor T-shirt Company - you know what we want? A sexy 
dishwashing shirt\", said the people. And lo, the Ann Arbor T-shirt Company did deliver.", 
"base_price"=>"15.0", "meta_description"=>"Funny Bar, Party, Pick-up Line T-shirt", 
"meta_keywords"=>"bar crawl shirt, adult humor shirt, inneuendo shirt, bad taste shirt, 
dirty joke shirt", "product_line_tokens"=>"1", "store_ids"=>["", "102", "15"], 
"taxonomy_ids"=>[""], "product_type"=>"T-shirt", "shipping_category"=>"T-shirt",  
"tax_category"=>"Taxable", "marketplace"=>"1", "art_status"=>"Awaiting Approval", 
"artist_id"=>"4", 
"default_artwork_id"=>"343", "color_ids"=>["", "14"], "base"=>"0", 
"special_instructions"=>"", 
"artworks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"dimensions"=>"10x12", "width"=>"9.4", "height"=>"8.5", 
"from_top"=>"1.0", "from_center"=>"0.0", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"342"}, "1"=>
{"dimensions"=>"14x16", "width"=>"12.9", "height"=>"11.6", "from_top"=>"1.0", 
"from_center"=>"0.0", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"343"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Idea", 
"id"=>"bpul_dishes"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 6 ORDER BY 
`users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 Idea Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `ideas`.* FROM `ideas` WHERE `ideas`.`deleted` = 0 AND  
`ideas`.`permalink` = 'bpul_dishes' ORDER BY `ideas`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 1
 Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON   
`roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `users_roles`.`user_id` = 6 ORDER BY name 
asc,  
`roles`.name ASC
Unpermitted parameters: stores_ids, taxonomies_ids
```

Answer (score 3):

Where is `@ideas` coming from in your view?  Have you tried this:

views/ideas/edit.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "ideas_nav" %>

<h1><%= @idea.working_name %></h1>

<div id="idea_show_container">
  <%= form_for @idea  do |f| %>
    <div id="basic_details" class="idea-show-columns">
      <%= render :partial => 'idea_basic_edit', :locals => {:f => f} %>
      <%= render :partial => 'comments', :locals => {:f => f}  %>
      <%= render :partial => 'mockups', :locals => {:f => f} %>
    </div>

    <% if current_user.has_copywriter_access? %>
       <div id="copy_details" class="idea-show-columns">
        <%= render :partial => 'copy_edit', :locals => {:f => f}  %>
       </div>
    <% end %>

    <% if current_user.has_artist_access? %>
        <div id="art_details" class="idea-show-columns ">
            <%= render :partial => 'art_edit', :locals => {:f => f} %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: that makes a lot more sense. Thank you. I am no longer getting an error, but for some reason any changes I make in the form do not get updated when I click submit. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: On newer RoR/Ruby (like RoR 4 and Ruby 2) you can also simplify the code to:
`<%= render 'idea_basic_edit', f: f %>`
Concerning the update issue: You need to post your controller config.

Comment: I would check out how your controller is handling all of the fields coming back and monitor the logs to see what the request parameters are coming from the form.  You might also want to look into using `f.fields_for` in your `_idea_basic_edit.erb` partial.  Documentation:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: @CDub: I don't think `f.field_for` is necessary, because this is not supposed to be a nested form.

Comment: @AWM - you're probably right, but without seeing the controller code, it was just a possible hunch. :)

Comment: @anmaree yeah, I'm guessing that there's something different between the params you're receiving to the controller from form submission and what the controller is trying to match on.  A log entry for this form post would be helpful in debugging that.

Comment: do I find a log entry in my terminal? I will post whatever necessary

Comment: Yeah, so from your app root:  `tail -f log/development.log`, clear the terminal, then click the form button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40759/discussion-between-cdub-and-anmaree)

Comment: Even after passing the builder into locals problem persists,then you need to check whether the nested fields does contain any other nested fields which does not passing variables into locals

Answer (score 1):

You want `:locals` rather than `@ideas`.  Like this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'idea_basic_edit', :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

That should make the value `f` available within the partial.

Comment: Note the comment from AWM in the other answer for Rails4.2, which seems to not support the "locals" method any more, making older, formerly-working code break with the same error as the OP.